# Silverlight HtmlPage.Window.Navigate

Tags: silverlight

```
void btnInfo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
   Uri u = new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute); 
   MessageBox.Show(u.ToString()); 
   HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(u); 
}
```

I'm trying to get my app to go to a URL.

I have a button which when clicked will bring up a popup box showing the URL but I can't seem to get the browser to go to the URL.

Anybody struck this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested your code - works fine. Do you have pop up blockers or something like that enabled that could interfere with your code?

Comment: Ah your right. Something in my Chrome must be stopping it. It works fine in IE.

Thanks